# Angular2: Toggle buttons are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to show Material 2 toggle buttons in a `md-list`. No idea why are they appearing as radio buttons.

```
<md-list>
  <md-button-toggle-group #group="mdButtonToggleGroup">
    <md-list-item><md-button-toggle>First Button</md-button-toggle></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item><md-button-toggle>Second Button</md-button-toggle></md-list-item>
  </md-button-toggle-group>
</md-list>
```

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MaterialModule} from "@angular/material";
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [__platform_browser_private__.BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: Can you show plunker example... you code here works http://plnkr.co/edit/AiqtVcMFo8ShzLe18ArU?p=preview

Comment: It seemed to be working on plunker. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried  MaterialModule.forRoot() instead of  MaterialModule

Comment: `MaterialModule.forRoot()` has been deprecated. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Why don't you follow the answer recommendations first? Your angular cli is relatively old (with many many bugs solved on the way) "1.0.0-beta.24". I also experienced problems with lazy loading and etc.... and do not plan to downgrade my cli and node versions. In 90% of cases point 1 of my answer is real answer, even if you do not believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it works in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AiqtVcMFo8ShzLe18ArU?p=preview

I would suggest this list to be checked:

1. always check version first (may be a bug in some older version)
2. I am not 100% sure that you can mix md-list child tag with md-button-toggle-group child... to check sources (by plunker works). Potential for problem is that you nesting of tags zigzagging...

Normal:

```
<md-list>
     <md-list-item>
     </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

and

```
<md-button-toggle-group>
     <md-button-toggle>
     </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

But you have:

```
<md-list>
    <md-button-toggle-group>
         <md-list-item>
             <md-button-toggle>
             </md-button-toggle>
         </md-list-item>
    </md-button-toggle-group>
</md-list>
```

3. css styles and code how was angular2 directives compiled, was not anyone
   overriding styles. Sometimes styles could go through all your code with /deep/ (or >>>) modifiers.
4. use  MaterialModule.forRoot() in AppModule